# Keep JS format code consistent between developers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, code-formatting, prettier, js-beautify

We keep having problem with Javascript developers are using different code format on the Editors. Some developers use VSCode, Sublime or PHPStorm. We are getting inconsistent code formatting when the developers create a PR (Github).

Is there a way a developer can run a command (npm format) which will format the code automatically. And also CI will do code format check?

Comment: Use ESLint or JSCS (JavaScript Code Style). Actually most linters have style configuration. And most JS editors also have a way to integrate linters - often built-in, bit sometimes it's an extra plugin or something. Once in place, it would signal for style changes. ESLint and JSCS (and probably others) can also auto-format to conform with the rules. I personally have the auto-format enabled on save in my editor but you can also have it as a Git hook or otherwise automated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for a code formatter, [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) is a great option. Using Prettier, you can have a central configuration (e.g., 4 spaced tabs, double quotes, etc.), and running a single command will clean your files.

You can extend this with [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky), which is my go-to choice for git hooks. Then, you can set up a pre-commit hook which will automatically clean your files using Prettier before committing any new code.

You can add the following to your `package.json` after adding Prettier and Husky as `devDependencies`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prettier-format": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.js'"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run prettier-format"
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use Onchange, which can be configured to run Prettier after saving any file changes: https://prettier.io/docs/en/watching-files.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Nx](https://github.com/nrwl/nx), it handles for you Prettier, TSLint and many many other stuff. Then you can run `nx format:check` (it can be also embedded in a pipeline easily by running `npm run format:check`) to check your formatting. `nx format:write` / `npm run format:write` will write the rules for you. Works really good in combination with VSCode option **Editor: Format on Save** turned **on**, highly recommending.